# DHCP Option 77 - malformed option

Tags: linux, tcp, wireshark, dhcp

I'am developing an industrial application based on an open source DHCP client.

I am setting a custom DHCP client class id (DHCP Option 77)

ipconfig /setclassid "Local Area Connection" "SOME_CUSTOM_CLASS_ID"

and in Wireshark I am capturing the DHCP handshake. The custom class id is present in the DHCP request, but wireshark has the Option 77 info highlighed with the error "malformed option".

Referring to RFC 3004 standard i found  that each instance of user class data should have a 1 octet prefix of the length that can fixe the problem and  dismiss DHCP all wireshark error.

The problem know is that some version of wireshark detect this error like version 1.10.6 other version can't detect like version 1.6.5.

Any ideas on this? Is it a bug in Wireshark ?

Answer (score 1):

First:

Dissection of DHCP Option 77 was first included in Wireshark 1.10 so Wireshark 1.6 and Wireshark 1.8 don't know about this option and thus don't show any error specifically about that option.

Second:

I'm a bit unclear as to your question:

Are you asking why Wireshark 1.6 doesn't show an error which is correctly shown in
Wireshark-1.10  ?

If so, please see 'First' above.

if not please clarify.

Comment: yes i want to know  why Wireshark 1.6 doesn't show an error which is correctly shown in Wireshark-1.10 ? I think that i get my answer in "First" ;) many thanks

Comment: Referring to RFC 3004 standard i found that each instance of user class data should have a 1 octet prefix of the length that can fixe the problem and dismiss DHCP all wireshark error.  => Could you please confirm this information ?

Comment: All I can say is that's the way the Wireshark 1.10 code to dissect option 77 is written; For each instance: 1 byte length followed by length bytes of data.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft introduced an incompatible format which is described at [2.2.6.1 User Class Option Sent by DHCPv4 Client to DHCPv4 Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd358019.aspx). The format is now:

- Option Code (77)
- Option Length
- User_Class_Data (variable length)

Wireshark only supports the RFC 3004 format in Wireshark 2.0 (and I guess also the upcoming 2.2). For more details on various implementations, see [this ask.wireshark.org](https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/35332/dhcp-option-77-malformed-option).